# Dropdown menu does not appear in html5-css3

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make my site "by hand" (only with code) and I am new on Web 
developing.

I have a problem ...

I tried to make a dropdown menu as you see in my code. The problem is that 
it works only when I am in page "0.Home.html".
When I am in the other pages the dropdown menu does not work ....

As you see in all the pages I have related the page with the same "myStyle.css"
file, and I use the same tag  (html5 only) in all the files ....

Can you help to correct my mistake so I will learn from you how to do it with 
the right way ?

I have posted my code ...

Thanks in advance !

File "0.Home.html"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="el">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="" >
  <meta name="description"
 content="Αρχική">
  <title>Αρχική Σελίδα</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css"/>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href=""/>
</head>

<body id="top">

<div id="header">
  <figure class="lorie-photos">
    <img src="" alt=""
 width="297" height="245"/>
  </figure>
  <h1 id="title1">AAAAAAAA</h1>
  <h3 id="title2">Mathematician - Computer Scientist</h3>
</div>

<nav>
 <ul>
    <li>Αρχική</li>
    <li><a href="1.Programming.html">Προγραμματισμός</a>
     <ul>
            <li>Η γλώσσες C και C++</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα JAVA</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα PHP</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα JAVASCRIPT</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="2.Algoriths.html">Αλγόριθμοι</a></li>
    <li><a href="3.DataStructures.html">Δομές Δεδομένων</a></li>
    <li><a href="4.DataBases.html">Βάσεις Δεδομένων</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

  <hr/>
  
  <h1>Βιογραφικό</h1>

  <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------ -->
  
  <p><a href="#top">Επιστροφή στην κορυφή της σελίδας</a></p>
  
  <hr/>
  
  <div id="footer">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li>Αρχική</li>
      <li><a href="1.Programming.html">Προγραμματισμός</a></li>
      <li><a href="2.Algoriths.html">Αλγόριθμοι</a></li>
      <li><a href="3.DataStructures.html">Δομές Δεδομένων</a></li>
      <li><a href="4.DataBases.html">Βάσεις Δεδομένων</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com" title="facebook">facebook</a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/" title="twitter">twitter</a>
      <a href="http://instagram.com/" title="instagram">instagram</a>
      <a href="http://www.france24.com/en/rss/" title="RSS feeds">
     RSS feeds</a>
    </p>
    &copy; Copyright 2016
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

File "1.Programming.html"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="el">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="" >
  <meta name="description"
 content="Προγραμματισμός">
  <title>Προγραμματισμός</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css"/>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href=""/>
</head>

<body id="top">

<div id="header">
  <figure class="lorie-photos">
    <img src="" alt=""
 width="297" height="245"/>
  </figure>
  <h1 id="title1">AAAAAAAA</h1>
  <h3 id="title2">Mathematician - Computer Scientist</h3>
</div>

<nav>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="0.Home.html">Αρχική</a></li>
    <li>Προγραμματισμός</li>
     <ul>
            <li>Η γλώσσες C και C++</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα JAVA</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα PHP</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα JAVASCRIPT</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="2.Algoriths.html">Αλγόριθμοι</a></li>
    <li><a href="3.DataStructures.html">Δομές Δεδομένων</a></li>
    <li><a href="4.DataBases.html">Βάσεις Δεδομένων</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

  <hr/>
  
  <p><a href="0.Home.html">Επιστροφή στην Αρχική</a></p>
  <h1>Προγραμματισμός</h1>

  <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------ -->
  
  <p><a href="#top">Επιστροφή στην κορυφή της σελίδας</a></p>
  
  <p><a href="0.Home.html">Επιστροφή στην Αρχική</a></p>
    
  <hr/>
  
  <div id="footer">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="0.Home.html">Αρχική</a></li>
      <li>Προγραμματισμός</li>
      <li><a href="2.Algoriths.html">Αλγόριθμοι</a></li>
      <li><a href="3.DataStructures.html">Δομές Δεδομένων</a></li>
      <li><a href="4.DataBases.html">Βάσεις Δεδομένων</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com" title="facebook">facebook</a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/" title="twitter">twitter</a>
      <a href="http://instagram.com/" title="instagram">instagram</a>
      <a href="http://www.france24.com/en/rss/" title="RSS feeds">
     RSS feeds</a>
    </p>
    &copy; Copyright 2016
  </div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

File "2.Algoriths.html"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="el">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="" >
  <meta name="description"
 content="Αλγόριθμοι">
  <title>Αλγόριθμοι</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css"/>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href=""/>
</head>

<body id="top">

<div id="header">
  <figure class="lorie-photos">
    <img src="" alt=""
 width="297" height="245"/>
  </figure>
  <h1 id="title1">AAAAAAAA</h1>
  <h3 id="title2">Mathematician - Computer Scientist</h3>
</div>
 
<nav>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="0.Home.html">Αρχική</a></li>
    <li><a href="1.Programming.html">Προγραμματισμός</a></li>
     <ul>
            <li>Η γλώσσες C και C++</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα JAVA</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα PHP</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα JAVASCRIPT</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Αλγόριθμοι</li>
    <li><a href="3.DataStructures.html">Δομές Δεδομένων</a></li>
    <li><a href="4.DataBases.html">Βάσεις Δεδομένων</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

  <hr/>
  
  <p><a href="0.Home.html">Επιστροφή στην Αρχική</a></p>
  <h1>Αλγόριθμοι</h1>
  
  <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------ -->
  
  <p><a href="#top">Επιστροφή στην κορυφή της σελίδας</a></p>
  
  <p><a href="0.Home.html">Επιστροφή στην Αρχική</a></p>
    
  <hr/>
  
  <div id="footer">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="0.Home.html">Αρχική</a></li>
      <li><a href="1.Programming.html">Προγραμματισμός</a></li>
      <li>Αλγόριθμοι</li>
      <li><a href="3.DataStructures.html">Δομές Δεδομένων</a></li>
      <li><a href="4.DataBases.html">Βάσεις Δεδομένων</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com" title="facebook">facebook</a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/" title="twitter">twitter</a>
      <a href="http://instagram.com/" title="instagram">instagram</a>
      <a href="http://www.france24.com/en/rss/" title="RSS feeds">
     RSS feeds</a>
    </p>
    &copy; Copyright 2016
  </div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

File "3.DataStructures.html"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="el">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="" >
  <meta name="description"
 content="Δομές Δεδομένων">
  <title>Δομές Δεδομένων</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css"/>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href=""/>
</head>

<body id="top">

<div id="header">
  <figure class="lorie-photos">
    <img src="" alt=""
 width="297" height="245"/>
  </figure>
  <h1 id="title1">AAAAAAAA</h1>
  <h3 id="title2">Mathematician - Computer Scientist</h3>
</div>

<nav>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="0.Home.html">Αρχική</a></li>
    <li><a href="1.Programming.html">Προγραμματισμός</a></li>
     <ul>
            <li>Η γλώσσες C και C++</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα JAVA</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα PHP</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα JavaScript</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="2.Algoriths.html">Αλγόριθμοι</a></li>
    <li>Δομές Δεδομένων</li>
    <li><a href="4.DataBases.html">Βάσεις Δεδομένων</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

  <hr/>
  
  <p><a href="0.Home.html">Επιστροφή στην Αρχική</a></p>
  <h1>Δομές Δεδομένων</h1>

  <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------ -->

  <p><a href="#top">Επιστροφή στην κορυφή της σελίδας</a></p>

  <p><a href="0.Home.html">Επιστροφή στην Αρχική</a></p>
    
  <hr/>
  
  <div id="footer">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="0.Home.html">Αρχική</a></li>
      <li><a href="1.Programming.html">Προγραμματισμός</a></li>
      <li><a href="2.Algoriths.html">Αλγόριθμοι</a></li>
      <li>Δομές Δεδομένων</li>
      <li><a href="4.DataBases.html">Βάσεις Δεδομένων</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com" title="facebook">facebook</a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/" title="twitter">twitter</a>
      <a href="http://instagram.com/" title="instagram">instagram</a>
      <a href="http://www.france24.com/en/rss/" title="RSS feeds">
     RSS feeds</a>
    </p>
    &copy; Copyright 2016
  </div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

File "4.DataBases.html"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="el">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="" >
  <meta name="description"
 content="Βάσεις Δεδομένων">
  <title>Βάσεις Δεδομένων</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css"/>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href=""/>
</head>

<body id="top">

<div id="header">
  <figure class="lorie-photos">
    <img src="" alt=""
 width="297" height="245"/>
  </figure>
  <h1 id="title1">AAAAAAAA</h1>
  <h3 id="title2">Mathematician - Computer Scientist</h3>
</div>

<nav>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="0.Home.html">Αρχική</a></li>
    <li><a href="1.Programming.html">Προγραμματισμός</a></li>
     <ul>
            <li>Η γλώσσες C και C++</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα JAVA</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα PHP</li>
            <li>Η γλώσσα JAVASCRIPT</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="2.Algoriths.html">Αλγόριθμοι</a></li>
    <li><a href="3.DataStructures.html">Δομές Δεδομένων</a></li>
    <li>Βάσεις Δεδομένων</li>
 </ul>
</nav>

  <hr/>
  
  <p><a href="0.Home.html">Επιστροφή στην Αρχική</a></p>
  <h1>Βάσεις Δεδομένων</h1>
  
  <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------ -->
  
  <p><a href="#top">Επιστροφή στην κορυφή της σελίδας</a></p>
  
  <p><a href="0.Home.html">Επιστροφή στην Αρχική</a></p>
  
  <hr/>
  
  <div id="footer">
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="0.Home.html">Αρχική</a></li>
      <li><a href="1.Programming.html">Προγραμματισμός</a></li>
      <li><a href="2.Algoriths.html">Αλγόριθμοι</a></li>
      <li><a href="3.DataStructures.html">Δομές Δεδομένων</a></li>
      <li>Βάσεις Δεδομένων</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com" title="facebook">facebook</a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/" title="twitter">twitter</a>
      <a href="http://instagram.com/" title="instagram">instagram</a>
      <a href="http://www.france24.com/en/rss/" title="RSS feeds">
     RSS feeds</a>
    </p>
    &copy; Copyright 2016
  </div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

File "myStyle.css"

```css
/* The background image */
body{
  background-image: url('../Photos/0.Background.jpg');
  background-size: 1000000%;
}

/* Header formatting */
#header{
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Title formatting */
#title1{
  font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50;
}

#title2{
  font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30;
}

/*************************************************************************/
/****************** Main Navigation menu formatting **********************/
/*************************************************************************/

nav{
 /*margin: 100px auto;*/
 text-align: center;
}

nav ul{
 list-style: none;
 background: #efefef;
 background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%); /* Firefox */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); /* Opera */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%); /* Safari */
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
 padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
}

nav ul:after{
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 display: block;
}

nav ul li{
 float: left;
 padding: 25px;
}

nav ul li:hover{
 background: #4b545f;
 background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
 color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul li a:hover{color: #ffffff;}

/*************************************************************************/
/************ Navigation Programming submenu formatting ******************/
/*************************************************************************/

nav ul ul{
 background: #5f6975;
 padding: 5;
 border-radius: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 display: none;
}

nav ul ul li{
 float: none; 
 border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul{
 display: block;
}

nav ul li a:hover > ul{
 display: block;
}

nav ul ul li a{
 padding: 25px;
 color: #ffffff;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover{
 background: #4b545f;
}

/*************************************************************************/

/* Headers h1, h2, h3 formatting */
h1{
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: red;
}

h2{
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Hyperlinks formatting */
a:link{color: blue;}
a:visited{color: purple;}
a:focus{color: maroon;}
a:hover{color: green;}
a:active{color: blue;}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

/* index-group formatting */
#index-group{
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Photos formatting */
.lorie-photos{
  float: left;
}

.photo{
  border-bottom: none;
}

figcaption{
  color: maroon;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Paragraphs line-height */
p{
  line-height: 150%;
  font-size: large;
}

/* Lists formatting */
ul, ol{
  font-size: large;
  line-height: 150%;
}

/* Footer formatting */
#footer{
  text-align: center;
}

/*
font-style: italic;
line-height: 150%;
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a second look at your 0.home.html file and compare your list element layout to your other pages.

In order for a list to contain a `<ul>` element, the `<ul>` must be **nested within** the `<li>`. Your other pages do not do this, which is why your menu isn't working.

Comment: My friend I SAW IT .... I had a mistake ..... THANK YOU for your valuable help ! I am just new in web programming !